# laptop not power on after travelling

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

every one

i travelled from chicago to virginia in bus and i put my laptop lenovo w530 on my back pack and my laptop not fell down no other damages . but after coming to home i try to turn on my laptop i cant when i press the power button its getting one beep sound and went turned off please help me i have important data base files and i have one tb memory in my harddrive which is almost full .please help me to figure out this proble. i take out my battery harddrive and memory and replaced everything but still iam facing the same problem . i dont have any other laptops please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this problem may related to hardware...so I think you should go to any Lenovo Customer Support.

Anyway, you can keep your laptop's harddrive...your data still be there.